# ms access 2013 vba join or concat values from multiple values list box

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have one form FORM1 with one field named FIELD1 which is listbox with many values and it is configured as Multi-select = extended.
The data from this form I want to be inserted via ODBC to MS SQL server database and table.

If the table is in MS ACCESS I how to configure it to be with multi-values field.

But in MS sql server I don't know.

I have an idea;
When the user select values from this list box, and press button for save record, the values to be joined or concatenate with separator; for example or - (doesn't matter) and joined text to be written in the SQL server field.

Example:

```
FIELD1 values:
             Val1
             Val2
             Val3
             Val4
```

The user selecting Val1, Val3, Val4
onClick event in VBA something like this

```
SQLSTRING = [forms]![FORM1].[FIELD1].value.join(';')
```

and as result in the MS SQL TABLE to be written Val1;Val3;Val4

after that

```
insert into MSSQLTABLE set MSSQLFIELD = SQLSTRING
```

How to configure the form to save `SQLSTRING`  vs `FIELD1`?

Comment: This is a terrible way to store data. Multiple values in a single cell is a nightmare to work with. You should properly normalize this and have three rows.

Answer (score 0):

Three separate fields might even be better than all in one.

However if you really must: code must loop through the listbox and concatenate.
Review: [Allen Browne - listbox](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html)